# How to get a core dump from a service started by xinetd on Ubuntu Precise

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, coredump, xinetd

I want to debug a service which fails with `SIGPIPE`. So I installed a signal handler for `SIGPIPE` and called `abort()` in it to get a core dump.

But I get none. I've set `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core` to get the core dump into `tmp` and I set with both `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `ulimit -c unlimited`

So, how can I get a core dump?

My xinetd-service files look as following:

```
service netmaumau
{
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    port        = 8899
    type        = UNLISTED
    flags       = KEEPALIVE
    disable     = no
    wait        = yes
    user        = heiko
    instances   = 1
    cps         = 1 10
    server      = /long/path/to/nmm-server
    server_args = -a
    log_on_success = PID HOST EXIT
    log_on_failure = HOST
}
```

Comment: Check with `getrlimit()` value of RLIMIT_CORE in Your service (is it actually unlimited).

Comment: Thanks, adding `struct rlimit rl = { RLIM_INFINITY, RLIM_INFINITY };
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rl);` was the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding

```
struct rlimit rl = { RLIM_INFINITY, RLIM_INFINITY }; 
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rl);
```

solved the problem